# App crashes on sudden navigation changes iOS

Tags: ios, crash, nsmutablearray, uitabbarcontroller, nsarray

i am creating an iPhone application with tabbar controller. I have two tabs with tableview controller. In both tabs some web service calls are there and it updates the table contents. I am using a loading indicator and all the service calls are performing on background thread and UI updates on mainthread with `waitUntilDone:YES`. In normal case everything is working perfect.

But the issue is,if I do sudden changes of tabs repeatedly the app crashes with error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x382a62a3 0x3338d97f 0x381f1b75 0x1521f9 0x362fb545 0x362e030b 0x362f77c7 0x362b3803 0x312d1d63 0x312d1901 0x312d2835 0x312d221b 0x312d2029 0x362b98eb 0x3827b6cd 0x382799c1 0x38279d17 0x381ecebd 0x381ecd49 0x3a0ec2eb 0x363042f9 0xcd317 0xc0b70)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I know, its because try to access values from NSArray where there is no contents. But, is there any common reason for this? I mean, if I do tab changes in normal speed there is no issue. But if I try to change the tabs, just after the loading indicator ends, the app crashes. I am not able to track this on the code. Crash is happening in `main.m`

Please share your ideas.

**Update**

The issue was happening in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

at

```
   songTitle.text = [songTitleSH objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    albumTitle.text = [albumNameSH objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    artistName.text = [artistNameSH objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    commentDateLbl.text = [playDateSH objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

i am getting NULL values in these arrays, that caused the issue. So, how can I overcome this issue? Any idea?

Comment: You'll have to post some code related to the array. Also, add an exception breakpoint to see where the crash is happening.

Comment: There are so many codes in both viewcontrollers and using NSArrays so many places. So i am not sure which should I add. Also, where should i use exception breakpoints? I am just asking for some general scenarios.

Comment: try from the beginning ie; view did load or tab:did select or cell for row index.

Comment: In the breakpoint navigator at the bottom hit + and select exception breakpoint.  This will pause the program at the line of code that crashes.

Comment: @Fogmeister that was really cool! Now I got the correct crash point. Thanks :)

Comment: I have updated my question please check.

Comment: try to set an "exception breakpoint" this will show you where the exception is raised